# Quaternion representation and Haar measure of $SU(3)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Do we have easily and practically useful quaternion representation for $SU(3)$ group element and for Haar measure?

Also, is $SU(2)$ really  simplified in the quaternion base?

Comment: you can find this representation in https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0211056

Comment: I found previously this paper.  but it is does`t state the expression for  Haar measure.

Comment: OK, I have added the Haar measure to the answer box (too long now for a comment)

Answer (score 2):

The Haar measure of $\text{SU}(3)$ is given by

$$
dV = \sin 2\beta \sin 2b \sin 2\theta \sin^2 \theta\; d\alpha\; d\beta\; d\gamma\;
d\theta\; da\; db\; dc\; d\phi,
$$
for the parameterization
$$U(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\theta,a,b,c,\phi) = e^{i\lambda_3 \alpha} e^{i\lambda_2 \beta}e^{i\lambda_3 \gamma} e^{i\lambda_5 \theta} e^{i\lambda_3 a} e^{i\lambda_2 b} 
e^{i\lambda_3 c} e^{i\lambda_8 \phi},
$$
in terms of the [Gell-Mann matrices.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices)

See [The geometry of $\text{SU}(3)$.](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9708015) For the alternative representation in terms of quaternions, see [Explicit closed-form parametrization of SU(3) and SU(4) in terms of complex quaternions and elementary functions.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0211056)

---

For the record, I also give the corresponding (much simpler) result for $\text{SO}(3)$,
$$dV=\sin 2\theta\;d\alpha \;d\beta\;d\theta,$$
in the quaternion parameterization
\begin{align}
O&=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\alpha\sigma_2}&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&e^{i\theta\sigma_2}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\beta\sigma_2}&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix},\;\;\sigma_2={{0\,-i}\choose{i\;\;\,0}}.
\end{align}
See [arXiv:1405.3115](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3115)

Comment: is it Haar measure that your state above working for SU(3) quaternion representation in the cited article?

Comment: yes, this is the invariant measure (not yet normalized)